# How to import latitude/longitude data correctly into MySQL?

Tags: mysql, decimal, latitude-longitude, load-data-infile

I've got a dataset of city names with their corresponding latitudes/longitudes that I've loaded into a MySQL table, like so:

city_id | city_name | latitude DECIMAL(9,6) | longitude DECIMAL(9,6)

Typical latitude/longitude coordinates might look like this: 54.284758 / 32.484736.

However, I'm only getting values with a scale of 2 to appear correctly in my table, in other words, the equivalent of DECIMAL(5,2). The data is uploaded from a text CSV that's been exported from OpenOffice Calc for UTF-8 purposes. I know OpenOffice has some problems with decimals but the full latitude/longitudes are certainly in the exported CSV. If I open the CSV with Notepad, the data is fine.

Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
Got it working, thanks for the all the input. I recreated everything from scratch, new schema file (I'm using an ORM), new CSV export, new table, new LOAD DATA INFILE, and it works with the correct decimal output. Beats me.

Comment: When you say "incorrect" in your table, do you mean when you type "SELECT * FROM mytable" at a MySQL prompt?  Or do you have a viewer?

Comment: @Tenner.... I'm using MySQL workbench, but the result is the same when I pull a coordinate via PHP.

Comment: Given the data types being `DECIMAL(9,6)`, and the CSV is correct when you view it in Notepad - something's up with whatever you're using to import the data.  Have a look at using the MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE instead in case it bypasses whatever issue you're encountering: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: @OMG Ponies... Thanks, I'm using LOAD DATA INFILE to import the CSV. Just had a look at the syntax again but can't see anything that should affect it. There's the SET clause but I must admit I don't understand it well enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be overkill for your needs, but when working geographic data you may want to consider using [MySQL Spatial Extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html).

I'll add that the datatype you're currently using is enough to represent the data as it is in your CSV file.  There is either something in your importer that is chopping it off at import time, or whatever you're using to view the data is truncating it.

Comment: Not sure what this link was referencing... but the Spatial Extensions doesn't seem to exist..  Here is the updated reference from 8.0.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-types.html

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a string data type such as varchar for storing Lat, Long. I am working on an app that makes extensive use of these coordinates and I haven't ran into any problems storing it as a string. Storing it as a number you will run into precision issues.

Just something to consider.

Comment: Thanks Lukasz. What did you mean by precision issues? I won't be using the data in a very strict manner. Only to generate some Google Map coordinates and mini-apps on top of that. I would have thought that a scale of 6 is pretty accurate?

Comment: How do you sort?  Or search within a radius?

It seems like storing these as strings would result in a lot of unnecessary run-time casting.

Comment: Precision wise I would recommend using a string or a large enough decimal. For example using float the following can happen. I have this coordinate that was returned from Bing Maps, 43.371240452765925 storing that value as a float results in 43.3712404527659. It’s not a huge error but it is an error. As for sorting, T-SQL sorts using the Lexicographic order which means that string and numbers will be sorted in similar way, so there is no need to cast.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just declare the fields as having type DOUBLE in your MySQL table? The qualifiers for number of digits and digits after the decimal point are optional.

Comment: Thanks, will try that in a moment, but like the MySQL manual says, DOUBLE/FLOAT isn't the right format when exact precision is needed, whereas DECIMAL is.